# Current capybara-bootstrap-datepicker is not work with japanese locale

Tags: capybara, rspec-rails, capybara-webkit

Current capybara-bootstrap-datepicker is not work with japanese locale

When I run the Rspec it give me following error

Failure/Error: select_date(Date.yesterday, xpath: "//input[@id='select_year_month']", datepicker: :bootstrap, format: "%Y/%m/%d")

Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css ".month" with text "Jul"

As of the month display are in ja locale like 1月", "2月", "3月", "4月", "5月", "6月", "7月", "8月", "9月", "10月", "11月", "12月" instaed of "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"

Answer (score 1):

I've just released a new version of the [capybara-bootstrap-datepicker](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara-bootstrap-datepicker) gem with localized datepicker support.

An update to the 0.1.1 version should solve your issue.